# Mailer won't send email due to possible unmatched constraints: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

I'm working on a project for my school and when Students sign up, they must check their email for a link to activate their account. For around 10 students out of nearly 300, the email wasn't sent.

The logs show:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"account_activation", :email=>"example@gmail.com", :id=>nil}, possible unmatched constraints: [:id]
from app/views/user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb:9:in _app_views_user_mailer_account_activation_html_erb___3703118489382282531_47409448002620' from app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:6:inaccount_activation'
from app/models/user.rb:58:in `send_activation_email'
from (irb):3
```

No matter what I tried, I couldn't recreate the error (I changed the email for privacy)

users_controller.rb

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

User.rb

```
    def send_activation_email
        UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver
    end
```

user_mailer.rb

```
  def account_activation(user)
    @user = user
    mail( :to => @user.email, :subject => 'Account Activation | Student', :id => @user.activation_token)
  end
```

My account_activation_controller.rb

```
def edit
        user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
        if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
            user.activate
            log_in user
            flash[:success] = "Account activated!"
            redirect_to user
        else
            flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link"
            redirect_to root_url
        end
    end
```

My github is https://github.com/Conbonbot/Community_Service_Logger

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you check users table in database? Do the users that didn't receive emails  have activation_token value ?

Comment: Yes, all Users that sign up have an activation_token value

Comment: Your actions says edit but id is nil- something is wrong here. you cannot call edit action without specifying Id. can you provide edit link,routes and controller with edit action. `ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"account_activation", :email=>"example@gmail.com", :id=>nil}, possible unmatched constraints: [:id]`

Comment: I've added my account_activation_controller.rb